# Ember.js: How to access a route programmatically

Tags: ember.js, routes

As controllers are deprecated in Ember I try to get rid of them in my applications. So in all cases where I used the rout's method `getControllerFor('nameOfTheRoute')` to access other controller's methods or properties
I now would like to call something like `getRouteFor('nameOfTheRoute')` but this method does not exists. So what can I do to access other routes. I would be very thankful for any suggestion.

Edit:
I have an app, that is a bit like Sequel Pro for Mac OS. This app has a basic application layout with two areas one for tables (on the left) and one for table rows (on the right). Below both areas are buttons to perform actions on a table or a table row. In ember-speak these buttons are defined in the applications route. As long as no table is selected (hence there are no table rows and the rows-route is not loaded) the buttons for the rows are not active. If table rows get loaded into the rows area the buttons are getting activated. And here is the problem: When I click on a button for the rows I want to perform an action in the rows-route. When using a controller, I can use `getControllerFor()`and access the actions-hash. But how could I perform an action on the rows-route? Or how can change my setup to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to access other routes? If you want to access parent routes, send an action to the parent route. If those routes that you want to access are not parent routes, calling them are not suitable since it conflicts with DDAU. Maybe in that case, the behaviour you want to access should be placed in a service. Or defining a component more suitable for that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please refer to my edit in the question that hopefully explains what I want to achieve. And maybe you can tell me what DDAU is. Thanks.

Comment: In such case you should send an action to the route. DDAU is "data down, actions up" principle. You may look: [blog1](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/) , [blog2](https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/14/best-practices-data-down-actions-up), [discuss](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-ember-data-affects-data-down-actions-up/6975)